# Is FirebaseUser.getUid() constant for a given user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have authenticated my user using phone authentication, and the user object that is returned has this long string when I call user.getUid() :

dn27dhJK..... (some long string).

If I authenticate this user on some other device (using my phone number etc), will user.getUid() always be the same ?

EDIT: From the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

> public abstract String getUid ()
>
> Also: Google Play services Returns a string used to uniquely identify
>   your user in your Firebase project's user database. Use it when
>   storing information in Firebase Database or Storage, or even in your
>   own backend.
>
> This identifier is opaque and does not correspond necessarily to the
>   user's email address or any other field.

It is unclear if this id remains constant or not.

Comment: Why is this down voted? This is a legitimate question, as the documentation does not mention this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first verify the phone number (or first sign in with a social provider, or call `createUser`), a user account is created - and thus a new unique UID id created. From that moment on, that user/phone number will remain associated with that account/UID. No matter if they re-verify on the same or a different device.

If you [delete the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user), a new account+UID will be generated when you use that same phone number next time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "if you delete the account ". I take it that you mean I should make some explicit API call to delete the account, as opposed to the user just deleting my app from his device...

Comment: Indeed, deleting the account requires calling this API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: Why would an app developer want to delete a user account ? Does it cost something to keep the account around ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firebase Authentication in your project:

**Remember**

1. Firebase will generate a single unique key(i.e. UID) on registration of a/c whether using Email/Phone number.
2. This key remain associated to that  a/c untill a/c is exist in firebase authentication list.
3. If your app is uninstalled on  phone & then a/c is open in another then we can fetch that key from Firebase  cloud auth. service.( UID remain safe).

Comment: So are you saying that if the app is simply uninstalled, the firebase account still exists ? Also is there any way for the user to delete their firebase account (authenticated only with phone number), without me knowing it ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay documentation says that it is necessary to re-authenticate the user so that he can delete the account.   So, obviously you can remove that  by using delete() or set(null) to that node value.

Comment: @KaizerSozay  here is the complete documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

This Uid is created when the user signs up and is linked to the phone number that you used. When you sign in you will get the same uid. But if you try to sign up again with the same phone number, it will basically give an error saying this phone number is already signed up.
Hope that explains!

Comment: But then suppose a users phone gets damage and installs the app on a new phone, or he simply deletes the app and reinstalls it, then how will he sign into the app with the same phone number ?

Comment: He will simply type his phone number and continue with sign in. Why do you think there will be a problem? Uid is connected with that phone number and does not change

Comment: your answer is incorrect - I just tried it again, and there is no error saying the phone number is already signed up. I used this example here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Comment: Does the uId change?

Comment: No, it doesn't change. Atleast, not in the two times I tried it. But thats the problem - it isn't official stated if we can expect this to be constant or not. What if I installed on a new device ? What if it changes only every 10 times, or every 100 times...